# Para que sirve la política de retención en las anotaciones

Tags: java

Tengo una duda creando anotaciones. No acabo de entender la anotación [`@Retention`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html) y la política de retención.

Segun la [`API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html), lo que hace es indicar cuando descartar la anotación `:\ WTF??`

> Anotacion de politica de retencion. Las constantes de este tipo describen las politicas para retener las anotaciones. Se usan combinadas con la meta-anotacion `Retention` para especificar cuánto se deben retener las anotaciones.

Y tiene un enum con tres tipos de retenciones:

> **CLASS** Anotaciones guardadas en el fichero de la clase por el compilador pero no necesitan ser retenidas por la VM en tiempo de ejecución.
>
> **RUNTIME** Anotaciones guardadas en el fichero de la clase por el compilador y retenidas por la VM en tiempo de ejecución, pueden ser leidas por reflexión.
>
> **SOURCE** Anotaciones descartadas por el compilador.

*(nota, la traducción es propia, quizás no es del todo exacta)*

---

La verdad es que ninguna de las dos descripciones me aclara el tema, entiendo lo que dicen, pero:

- ¿Porqué es necesaria la política de retención y por tanto que se descarten las anotaciones?

Entiendo que tiene que ver con el tipo de compilación de Java y su transformación en bytecode,

- indica cuando transformar la funcionalidad de la anotación en bytecode?
- es una manera de ofuscar código?

Comment: Por lo que yo he visto, eso trata básicamente en qué momento es visible la anotación y dirve para su procesamiento. Por ejemplo, si la anotación está en momento class entonces puedes aprovechar las anotaciones para generar código Java en tiempo de pre compilación como lo hacen lombok, selma y mapstruct. Si las marcas como runtime, entonces puedes procesarlas en tiempo de ejecución vía reflexión como lo hace Spring.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza eso ya me parece más tangible! algún ejemplo de `RetentionPolicy.SOURCE`?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto te puede aclarar un poco el concepto

**RetentionPolicy.SOURCE**: No aparece cuando decompilas la clase

**RetentionPolicy.CLASS**: Aparece en la clase decompilada, pero no puede accederse a ella en tiempo de ejecución por medio de reflexión

**RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME**: Aparece en la clase decompilada,puede ser acedida en tiempo de ejecución por medio de reflexión con el método *getAnnotations()*

Realmente es una politica para controlar que anotaciones puede aparecer en la decompilación y tambien indicar si es accesible en tiempo de ejecución por reflexión

- **indica cuando transformar la funcionalidad de la anotación en bytecode?** En mi opinion, marca si es accesible por reflexion.
- **es una manera de ofuscar código?** Depende de como lo interpretes, no ofusca, directamente no va a mostrarla en el codigo decompilado

Un saludo